# Reading remote text file with AIR, spaces and links

Tags: actionscript, air

I have a text file(txt) in my web server. I will read the file contents and show it to user. The problem is that it does not show line separations and spaces the right way. Also i will need to activate possible links. For example if there is http://www.google.com then user can just click on the link and default browser opens it.

So far i have this:

```
var fileContents:String;

            try{

                var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
                myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoaded);
                myLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://my.website.com/test.txt"));

                function onFileLoaded(e:Event):void
                {
                    fileContents = String(e.currentTarget.data);
                    var alertMessage = fileContents;
```

I have done this same thing in java, but I am not so familiar with ActionScript.

Java code:

```
URL url = new URL(getString(R.string.url));

                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line);
                    total.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

                }
                str = total.toString();
                r.close();

                return str;
```

Links in java:

```
final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(sUrl);
            Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using the Text Layout Framework (TLF) from Adobe. You can import the text as HTML and it will create clickable links for any URL's found in the text. TLF is a bit unwieldy, but very powerful.

```
private var myTextFlow:TextFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(sourceText, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
```

If you are using Flex 4, can assign the resulting `TextFlow` object to one of the text components:

```
<s:RichText textFlow="{myTextFlow}" />
```

In an Actionscript project, you have to do a little more work to use the `TextFlow`. TLF uses an MVC approach. The `TextFlow` serves as the model, you can use a `Sprite` for the view, and a `ContainerController` as the controller:

```
private var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(container);
private var controller:ContainerController = new ContainerController(container, 800,600);
myTextFlow.flowComposer.addController(controller);
myTextFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am using Air 3.3 and when i try to add my source text to textFlow object, all i can read from it is TextFLow: [object TextFlow] any ideas ?

Comment: A `TextFlow` is a complex object, not a simple `String`, so you cannot just try to read from it or trace out it's value. You should probably look up other examples of working with TLF text and/or `TextFlow`'s. Here's [one to get you started](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/elements/TextFlow.html#includeExamplesSummary)...